# pass dynamic string

Tags: 7

i create a function which save data to db . here is my code

```
function create_db_entry($table_name, $fields) {
  $str='';
  foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {

    $str.="'".$key."'=>"."'".$value."',";


  }

 if(db_insert($table_name)->fields(array($str))->execute()) {

  }else {
    drupal_json_output("there is some problem, please try again"); exit;

  }

}
```

and here is my

```
$str='token_id'=>'f3c7b8b04a283e16645f3e885cd73ebf','uid'=>'1',
```

Now if i use this

```
db_insert($table_name)->fields(array('token_id'=>'f3c7b8b04a283e16645f3e885cd73ebf','uid'=>'1',))->execute();
```

it works fine. i want to use $str.

Can anybvody tell me how to do this

Thanks

Comment: So, well, just use `$str`? but why are you use syntax that is not even a PHP syntax to define it? Why isn't it `$str=array(` when you want to use it in place that accepts arrays only? And why to use name suggesting it's string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str='token_id'=>'f3c7b8b04a283e16645f3e885cd73ebf','uid'=>'1',
```

Is not valid PHP. The `fields()` method takes an associative array, so that's what you need to pass to it:

```
$arr = array(
  'token_id'=>'f3c7b8b04a283e16645f3e885cd73ebf',
  'uid'=>'1'  
);
...
db_insert($table_name)->fields($arr)->execute()
```

To build that dynamically:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
  $arr[$key] = $value;
}
```

Although at that point you're just duplicating `$fields`, so you might as well pass that directly to the db query.

With the best will in the world, I question the point of even having that function as it doesn't really add anything. If you're looking for a wrapper function Drupal already has [`drupal_write_record()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7).